# Screencloud stopped working properly on multiple screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome, snapshot

I have been using Screencloud for years as the main screenshot and snapping tool on Ubuntu. It has worked fine until I have update to Ubuntu 17.10.

Now, it started "switch desktops" when I try to Capture Selection. In details, I have 3 monitors (left, middle, right) where `Activities` and top bar is on the right one. When I try to capture selection, the app works only on the left screen. On the middle screen, **the right screen desktop appearas** when I want to capture selection. And on the right screen, I get blank or black screen. Just like right screen is temporarily moved to a middle screen, and the right screen gets empty screen injected.

Did anyone face this issue and how to fix it?

If screencloud does not work well on Ubuntu 17.10, can you propose another tool for it?!

**EDIT**

Ubuntu has already been set to log into "Ubuntu on Xorg"

Comment: This could be caused by Ubuntu 17.10 using Wayland by default. X.Org session can be selected in the login screen, it may solve the issue.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine It's already set as Ubuntu on Xorg. Any more ideas?